# Detecting Double click with javascript disabled

Tags: html

I have a action being performed on a button click for a page with no javascript, but I want to prevent that action being performed twice when a user double clicks.

Comment: why are you preventing to second click.is it a link?

Comment: If the javascript is disabled, and assume you found a way to detect the double click. What will you do when you detect it ? i.e. how will you handle the event ? in all cases you will need to take an action with JS then!

Comment: Suppose I have a "MoneyTranfer" button which deducts money from my account. So I want to prevent double click.As account is being debited twice on double clicks.

Comment: There might be a way, I'll try and set up a fiddle

Comment: You'll have to handle this in the backend, like preventing the second money transfers from the same user if the last transfer happened less than one second ago

Answer (score 2):

You need to store, using your form handler code, the submitted data from each request (at least for a little while) and then compare each set of submitted data to previously submitted data.

You can either do this across the entire set of data (which is more complex) or generate an ID token each time you create a form, store it in a hidden input, and compare only that (but then you may reject a deliberate second submission by someone who submits the form, hits back, changes the data in the form and makes another request).

Comment: I think that is the way to go. You just need to find a sane timeframe in which two deliberate requests are allowed to happen.